# How to display a Checkmark as text in a Dropdown Menu?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui

We recently re-wrote our software, which used to use the default ASP.NET controls. In one of our dropdowns, we'd populate the values from the DB and it shows a checkmark:

[image]

The item in the datbase is just the string `&#x2713;` which renders as the checkmark in the control.

Now, we use Telerik's Kendo UI for our controls. This just displays the flat text:

[image]

If I use the same code in a table element in correctly displays as a checkmark, so why does it not display correctly when used as a drop down item?

Edit:

Tried a few combinations based on the answer. Ignore the `- n` after the code, that's just supposed to be a "user friendly value" instead of a number / checkmark on the left hand side of the `-`.

Tried escaping it with both 1 and 2 `\` per their recommendation in the documentation, no such luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your template is probably displaying the content with `#: #` instead of `#= #`. Using `:` kendo encodes the HTMl entities, so your `&#` becomes text. The `=` sign tells kendo to display as raw HTML. [Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview).

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/Unozo). I have used DropDownList in the demo because I don't know if you mean DDL or Menu, but the template should work as well in any widget.

Comment: Unfortunately, had to un-select it as the answer. It worked in your linked demo but I was unable to confirm myself at the time. I've editted my post with the values I'm trying. None display correctly :(

Comment: @sab669 np, but you should post your widget js code, otherwise would be hard to guess the issue.